# Adding tags in Overpass QL

Tags: convert, overpass-api

I am trying to add a custom tag to everything in my Overpass query. As far as I understand this can be achieved with `convert`. But so far, this kind of statement:

```
convert way
      ::id=id(), 
      ::=::, 
      import_id=17;
```

drops all attributes except `id` and all way contents (`nd` refs), so only tags and id remain intact, and with the new tag added. Is is possible at all to make a complete copy of a set element with `convert`, or with any other means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design. Overpass API won't allow preparing data in a form which would be suitable for mass changes/mechanical updates. Although you can include geometry details in your result, it will be returned in a completely different format:

```
way({{bbox}});
convert way
      ::id=id(), 
      ::geom=geom(),
      ::=::, 
      import_id=17;
out geom;
```

Some other tools like osmconvert or osmium might be better suited for this task.